# How is it possible that network is still reachable even after disabling the only connection via nmcli?

Tags: networking, networkmanager

I've got a system with an ethernet connected over eth1 and managed by Network Manager. The connection has autoconnect set to `no` in it's settings. After boot the system has no internet access as `ping` commands fail. I'm able to turn the connection on just fine with `nmcli c up eth1` which makes `ping`s successful and has `ifconfig` report an ip address against eth1.

However, if I want to take the connection down again (with `nmcli c down eth1`), `ifconfig` no longer shows an ip address against the interface but `ping`s keep suceeding. How come that's possible? What is it that I'm missing here?

Comment: You could provide the *actual* resulting network configuration: `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route; ip neigh` three times: before when it doesn't work, in the middle when it starts working, and after when it keeps working while it's expected it shouldn't. (as well as telling what's the remote IP that is pinged)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the culprit. The manufacturer of the board I'm using seems to have added a script hook to NetworkManager, to be exectued at every device connection status change, which essentially includes bringing up the connection as it's very last step. Removing the part of the script responsible for that fixed this problem for me.

Why on earth they'd do something like that, rather than depend on NetworkManager's own automatic reconnection mechanisms really puzzles me, so if anyone has any idea please leave a comment.